# passport-google-oauth is showing error

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport-google-oauth

error is

```
Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=390055536156-bc61n4u6dlo8ttnjn3m29307ofccin97.apps.googleusercontent.com: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

[image: my settings at google console]

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: how are you using this?

Comment: react send info to server(node) and then node use passport-google-oauth